# Need help to search for a string and overwrite data to same location

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that writes data to the next empty column and it works perfectly when the record does not exist. However, I added code to search for the record (MyVal) and if found to ask if we should overwrite. When it asks the question if the user says no it exits the sub (this is correct behavior) but if the record exists I want it to write the data to the same location. I am pretty sure I have the "Else" in the wrong location and I don't know what code to write to tell it to write the data to the same location as the record found.

```
Sub Copy_To_Borrower_DBase()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim myVal As String
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim lCol As Long
MyNote = Sheets("Main").Range("F5").Value & _
         " already exists, do you want to overwrite?"
myVal = Sheets("Main").Range("F5").Value ' dropdown list

Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Borrower Database").Range("5:5").Find( _
       What:=myVal, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'locate column where to copy from

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Borrower Database")

If Not sourceRng Is Nothing Then
    Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Overwrite??")
    If Answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
Else
With ws2
Application.EnableEvents = False
lCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Column
    .Cells(5, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("F5").Value 'Borrower Name
    .Range(.Cells(6, lCol), .Cells(8, lCol)).Value = 
ws1.Range("G6:G8").Value 'Income, Credit Pmt and Car Pmt
    .Range(.Cells(9, lCol), .Cells(10, lCol)).Value = 
ws1.Range("G11:G12").Value 'Borrower Name
    .Cells(11, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("G15").Value 'Reserves
    .Cells(12, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("D15").Value 'Credit Score
    .Cells(13, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("D14").Value 'Rate
    .Cells(14, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("C14").Value 'Discount Point
Application.EnableEvents = True
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try debugging using F8 key. Step line by line and check where is the problem.

Comment: So if they press yes what should happen exactly? Presumably you need to write something to `sourcerng`.

Comment: @SJR I would execute a bunch of these values .Cells(13, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("D14").Value

Comment: Not sure I follow. Is it a case of using `.Cells(13, sourcerng.column).Value =...` instead?

Comment: That was the part I didn't know how to do it         .Cells(5, sourceRng.Column).Value = ws1.Range("F5").Value 'Borrower Name